# VS2008 how to change from Web Developer to C# Developer settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I just reinstalled vs2008 and accidentally selected Web Developer instead of C# Developer the first time it ran and now all my key bindings that I was used to are wrong.   How do I change it to C# Developer?

I tried devenv /resetsettings,  but it only reset my fonts and other settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tools->Import And Export Settings->Reset All Settings

This will give you an option to select a different setup (i.e. C# developer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the "additional keyboard mapping scheme" to Visual C# under Options -> Environment -> Keyboard?

Comment: Okay sorry, just found out that this setting really just affects the "additional" keyboard settings.

Comment: +1 not because the answer ... just thought the downvote was harsh!!

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy:

`Tools` > `Customize...` > `Keyboard`

Then change for one of the specified presets.