# ASP.net Development Setting

Tags: asp.net

I am using VS 2008 with SP1.During the start up ,i selected my option as "C# Development settings".Now i wish to turn it to "General development settings".How can i change it ?

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078551/vs2008-how-to-change-from-web-developer-to-c-developer-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools->Import And Export Settings->Reset All Settings

This will give you option to choose in which environment you want to work.